# Mobile game testing using Appium

Tags: testing, mobile, automation, automated-tests, appium

I want to learn how to test mobile games using Appium and Eclipse.

I didn't find something good to learn from it.

So if you please give me any clear tutorial to learn through it.

Thanks.

Comment: Firebase offers to test on game applications. Not sure much about it. but you might want to check that

Answer (score 2):

Appium is not a good option (at least for now) to test mobile games. Appium is using native test frameworks like **UIAutomator**, **Espresso** (Android) and **XCUITest** (iOS), that are basically implemented to test **apps build with native SDK**

Mobile games are mostly build with engines like **Unreal, Unity, Corona** ,etc. that have *no relation to native SDK and thus cannot be tested with native test frameworks without additional tweaks*.

Basically following issues to be addressed and add support for:

- find elements
- check action occurring in game
- check UI rendered properly

There are some projects where engineers are trying to use Appium with some additional ports, e.g. [Unity-Appium](https://github.com/UnityTech/GamesTestAutomationExample), but there is definitely nothing like Appium or Selenium that you can take and use like silver bullet.

Good luck!